# Why do I keep getting this error?

Tags: c, file, download

I've tried downloading the file from Safari and I've also tried downloading the file from Firefox, but no matter what, when I try to compile my files along with the object files, I keep getting this error:

```
print-all32.o: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's how I compile my files and the object file:

```
$ gcc -ansi -Wall -Werror -lm -o myprint-all print-all32.o grove.c
```

I can't figure out why this keeps happening. Help is greatly appreciated because this will probably become a very big issue in future programming projects/assignments.

And if you need it, here are the object files/other files I need to download:
http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~dekhtyar/101-Fall2013/labs/lab5.html

Comment: I've looked at both print-all.o and print-all32.o and they are the same. Indeed, both are for 64 bits machines (`ELF 64-bit LSB  relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`). If you are running in a 32 machine, ask your instructor to post again the 32 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to check first.

1. Are you using the files which are compatible with your system (32 bit or 64 bit)
2. Can you run 'make clean' before you compile the files. Can you regenerate the object file in your own system rather than using the object file supplied by the instructor.

Regards

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, I double checked and I'm using the 32 bit one which is compatible with unix4. I'll try the second piece of advice. :)

Comment: @Karen I'm sure azmuhak would be happy about an upvote *additionally* to accepting. (Just as a suggestion.) ;-)